# Branding issue with MacTeX 2013?

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex

After learning that TeX Live 2013 was released this Tuesday June 18, I downloaded the new [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/). I am just a bit puzzled though:

- The MacTeX homepage clearly presents the download as MacTeX-2013, but with a release date of May 30, 2013, i.e. before TeX Live 2013 was released (while MacTeX is based on TeX Live);
- At install, `MacTeX.pkg` greets me with a MacTeX-2012 title:
  [image: mactex install screen]

Has anyone experienced the same? Is there something wrong with my download (maybe the mirror wasn't up to date), or is the branding simply wrong on MacTeX 2013?

Comment: Same thing on Linux. I was told to wait 1-2 days for mirror sites to update that is all.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the info. Guess next year they should consider appending the version to the name of the download to avoid mirroring issues :)

Comment: Here is link for the image FYI  http://i.stack.imgur.com/gMbvA.jpg

Comment: I had this problem too. I downloaded the old version three times, from different sites. Until you open up to the splash page there is nothing to show you that it is the old version.

Comment: I'd say it is a bit problematic that they link directly to `MacTeX.pkg`, then one cannot see the age on the mirror of choice.

Comment: @daleif I've pointed out to the MacTeX people that this leads to an issue when they archive the pages: they all point to the same file, and getting the archived versions is then a bit of a pain. That said, I never use the link from the MacTeX page as I always grab from CTAN directly.

Comment: @JosephWright I do think most MacTeX users will get it via tug.org/mactex so some care should be in order. I didn't even know that TL13 was finished.

Comment: @daleif True, but this only pops up for a day or so while the mirrors update, so it's difficult to be too harsh!

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for reporting the issue!

Answer (score 3):

Releasing code to CTAN means that it gets installed first on one of the two 'master' nodes: [Cambridge](http://www.tex.ac.uk) (UK) or [DANTE](http://dante.ctan.org). The new material is then copied around the world to the network of mirror servers, a process that takes a little while. The TeX Live 2013 release was made on 2013-06-18 to the Cambridge master node. My 'nearest' mirror (Oxford, UK) updated by early on 2013-06-19, but it is 'close' both physically and in topology terms to Cambridge, so others may be slower: give it at least 48 hours.

To check which version you will download, you can look at the file date in the listing. The final testing build of MacTeX was made in late May 2013, and the `MacTeX.pkg` file for MacTeX 2013 is dates 2013-05-30. For the 'standard' TeX Live, you can tell if a mirror is up to date by checking the date of of the `archive` folder inside `[archive]/systems/texlive/tlnet/`, which again shouldbe 2013-05-30 (or later).

It's important to note that the 'release date' for TeX Live doesn't mean that every file is updated on that day. The final phase of testing is more or less people using the 'hope to release' code and making sure it works, so testing is done when there is no need to make any changes. As such, the file dates for the 'gold' version are always before the release date.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a `texlive2013.iso.sha25` `texlive2013.iso.md5` type checks for `MacTeX.pkg` to ensure the date and file integrity

Comment: @texenthusiast See http://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html for the MD5 value

Comment: I was expecting the `MacTeX.pkg.md5` value to sit in same place where `MacTeX.pkg` file exists like [`texlive2013.iso.md5`](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/). Inanycase it will help. Thanks